# Row_number() on filtered data

Tags: sql, rank

I am trying to find `row_number()` on filtered data. When I include the filter in the where clause, row_number is working as expected. But I am trying to put filter condition in the select case statement, but then it does not seem to work.

The reason why I do not want to put filter condition in the where clause is that I have other metrics in the same select sql statement. I tried with subquery approach aliasing the table and it works.

But I am wondering if there is any other better/efficient way of doing this.

```
--working with where clause - works
SELECT 
  order_id,
  ROW_NUMBER() over(
    PARTITION BY orderid, date_trunc('month',order_date) 
    ORDER BY order_date) 
FROM order
WHERE order_success='yes'

--working with sub query - works
SELECT 
  order.order_id,
  row_number() over(
    PARTITION BY temp.orderid, date_trunc('month',temp.order_date)
    ORDER BY temp.order_date) 
FROM order 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT order_id, order_date 
  FROM order 
  WHERE order_success='yes'
) temp_order ON order.order_id=temp_order.order_id

--trying to achieve with case statement/ does not work
SELECT 
  order_id,
  CASE WHEN order_success='yes' and ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY  orderid, date_trunc('month',order_date) ORDER BY order_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM order
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you only want to number your successful orders while selecting other orders, too. If so, you can include the success flag in the partition and use `CASE WHEN` to suppress the number on non-success rows.

```
select
  order_id,
  case when order_success = 'yes' then
    row_number() over(partition by order_success, orderid, date_trunc('month', order_date)
                      order by order_date)
  end as num
from order 
order by order_date;
```

(On a side note: Why is there `orderid` in the partition clause? Isn't this the order table's unique key?)

Comment: This is the test table I created(I should have said customer_id, instead of order_id). but in my actual scenario I have 4 fields to filter on and rank only filtered records in the correct order. I tried similar to what you suggested : case when order_success = 'yes' then
    row_number()  without including the filter column in the partition by. could you tell me what is the reason to include filter columns in the partition by clause? Thank you!

Comment: Okay. The technique remains the same: add the columns to the partition clause and extend the case when clause.

Comment: can you tell me what is the reason to include filter columns in the partition by clause? I have 4 fields to filter on. So, Is doing it this way with case statement better over sub query with filtering separately? Please advise! Thank you!

Comment: The trick is to get all filtered rows into one partition. And well, if it's not only about equality like in `order_success = 'yes'`, then you'd even have to put the whle condition into the clause: `partition by case when order_success in ('yes', 'maybe') then 1 else 2 end, …)`. That may become cumbersome. Maybe your outer join approach turns out to be more readable then mine. I don't think one approach is better than the other. Faster maybe. I don't know. Just pick the one *you* like better.

Comment: It worked perfect after adding filter clause to partition by list. appreciate your help. I went with your approach since it eliminated so many sub queries.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the `ROW_NUMBER()` function to a sub-query and referencing it as an alias in the outer query:

```
SELECT 
  src.order_id,
  CASE 
    WHEN src.order_success='yes' AND src.MyWindowFunction = 1 THEN 1 
    ELSE 0 
  END
FROM (
  SELECT 
    order_id,
    order_success,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
      PARTITION BY orderid, date_trunc('month', order_date) 
      ORDER BY order_date
    ) AS MyWindowFunction
  FROM order
) src
```

Comment: I want row_number() to be calculated for the order_success=yes. but in the sub query you posted, ranking is done without this filter in the sub query. so, how is to going to rank them correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need an IN clause as you get rownumber() multiple times as 1 for a particular order_id. Its like at the same time where order_success='yes' for a single row for order_id say x you will get multiple rows via partition by as subgroups hence rownumbers would have multiple 1's and comparision would fail.

```
   select order_id, case when 
  order_success='yes' and row_number() 
   over(partition by 
   orderid,date_trunc('month',order_date) 
  order by order_date) IN (1) then max(1)else 
    max(0 )
    end from order
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you only want to count "yes"es or if you want the value to be `NULL` when the row does not have a "yes".

If you want to count "yes"s, then use a cumulative count:

```
select order_id,
       sum(case when order_success = 'yes' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by orderid, date_trunc('month', order_date) order by order_date)
from order o;
```

This seems more useful than having `NULL` values on non-"yes" rows.  You seem to be using Postgres, so this can be simplified to:

```
select order_id,
       count(*) filter (where order_success = 'yes') over (partition by orderid, date_trunc('month', order_date) order by order_date)
from order o;
```

You can wrap either of these in a `case` expression if you want `NULL` on non-"yes" rows.